# Setting custom variable in Scheduled Release trigger

Tags: azure-devops

I am AzureDevOps for creating a new Release from Scheduled trigger from artifact. Same pipeline can create the release manually.

How can i set the value of a Custom Variable for Release that is triggered from Schedule? One of the Task in my pipeline uses that Variable.

Comment: What value do you have in mind? I don't understand what the goal is; the release is triggered from the schedule using whatever variables are part of the release. What's going to control the variable's value on a release by release basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set two stages separately, one for manual triggering and one for schedule triggering, then you only need to set getting the variable value for the task in the stage triggered by the schedule.

You can customize a variable and set the value for the variable in Release Variables.
[image]

If you want to switch the trigger in one stage: manual or schedule, let the task determine whether to get the variable value according to different triggers. Then you can try to write a script in the powershell task to monitor the 
pipeline triggers.Get the variable value if the trigger is schedule.

Comment: that might work, in powershell how can i figure out if the Release is created from Schedule trigger or manual. In the predefined variable [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch), i don't see a variable for trigger type.

Comment: Ok, got it Release.Reason